# How to properly format pseudocode (algorithm) in LNCS (Lecture Notes in Computer Science)?

Tags: verbatim, algorithms, lncs

I know that when I need to paste the source code, I should use `\verb` or `\verbatim`. But how about pseudocode\algorithms? Should I use `\verb` or `\verbatim` as well? Can't really find any official Springer docs about this.

Maybe I should use `\algorithm`?

Comment: What is LNCS?...

Comment: @Jubobs: Sorry, edited the title. LNCS stands for Lecture Notes in Computer Science :)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 different LaTeX packages for pseudo code. Look at one article in the journal and pick the one looks most similar. Or don't use any at all: once I asked a CS professor which package he used for pseudo code and his answer was \begin{enumerate}.